# How to input unknown number of user strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string

How to read unknown number of user inputted strings ? Buffer represents where the inputted string should be stored and later passed to the collection of strings, n represents when the maximum of strings is allocated and than reallocate it. This code is how i tried in doing it but it gives me a segmentation fault:

```
char buffer[15];
char ** strings;
int c = 5;
int n = 0;
strings = malloc(c * sizeof(char *));
do
{
    if(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        if(n == c) strings = realloc(strings, (c *= 2) * sizeof(char *));
        strcpy(* (strings + n++), buffer);
    }
}while(buffer[0] != ' ' || buffer[0] != '\n');
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%s\n", * (strings + i));
free(strings);
```

Comment: You allocate space for the array of pointers, but you never set the pointers in that array to point to anything useful.  Where do you think the `strcpy` line is actually copying to?

Comment: @NateEldredge Can i make them point to various buffer strings, and if so how ?

Comment: With malloc, the same way you allocated space for the array itself.

Comment: The posted code does not compile! please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT: regarding: `strings = malloc(c * sizeof(char *));`  1) `c` is a meaningless variable name.  Please use variable names that indicate content or usage (or better, both)  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` to output both the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.

Comment: OT: regarding: `if(n == c) strings = realloc(strings, (c *= 2) * sizeof(char *));` 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) the function: `realloc()` can fail.  When it fails, the pointer `strings` will contain NULL, the result is an unrecoverable memory leak.  When calling `realloc()`, always assign the returned value to a 'temp' pointer, check that 'temp' pointer: if NULL, then cleanup and exit.  Otherwise, assign the target pointer from the 'temp pointer,

Comment: @user3629249 Thank you for the informative suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This code is how i tried in doing it but it gives me a segmentation fault:*

regarding:

```
strcpy(* (strings + n++), buffer);
```

this is trying to copy the contents of `buffer` using a pointer in `strings[]` as the pointer to the destination.

However, that pointer has not been set to point to memory that the application owns.

The result is undefined behavior (and as you have seen, can lead to a seg fault event.)

Suggest using: `strdup()` to set the pointer in `strings[]` to an allocated memory that contains the original input from `fgets()`.

```
strings[n] = strdup( buffer );
n++;
```

Of course, remember to pass each of the pointers in `string[]` and then `string` to `free()` before exiting the program, similar to:

```
for( int i=0; i<n; i++ )
{
    free( strings[i] );
}

free( strings );
```

Note that `fgets()` also inputs the trailing '\n' which you 'may' want to eliminate.  One good way to eliminate any trailing '\n' is:

```
buffer[ strcspn( buffer, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

EDIT:

A good way to write your application would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 

void cleanup( char **strings, size_t usedEntries );
 
 
int main( void )
{
    char buffer[15];
    char ** strings = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
 
    
    while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) )
    {
        if(buffer[0] == '\n' || buffer[0] == ' ')
        {
            break;
        }
            
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
            
        char ** temp = realloc(strings, n+1 * sizeof(char *));
        if( ! temp )
        {
            perror( " realloc failed" );
            cleanup( strings, n );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
            
        strings = temp;     
        *(strings + n++) = strdup(buffer);
    }
    
    for( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s\n", *(strings + i));
        
    cleanup( strings, n );
    return 0;
}


void cleanup( char **strings, size_t n )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i<n; i++ )
    {
        free( strings[i] );
    }
    free( strings );
}
```

Comment: What if I remove strcpy and  just declare it as * (strings + n++) = buffer, this is what i wanted, and then i don't know how to exit the loop.

Comment: the `buffer` degrades to a pointer to the first byte of the array `buffer`.  If you use this code, then ALL the entries in `strings[]`  will point to `buffer`.  If you examine (or print) all the 'used' entries in `strings[]`  you will find that they ALL point to the `buffer`, so they will all reference that last data read by `fgets()`.  Not what you want.

Comment: Could you verify my new code ? https://pastebin.com/muG13UvM

Comment: Links are not stable.  Please post the 'new code' as an addendum to your question.

Comment: The linked code shows that you have ignored almost everything that has been presented to you (except for cleaning up before exiting the program)